# Can't detect HDD in Windows Setup

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bios

today my pc did not start, after the bios loaded, the message "DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER' appeared. there are 3 HDDs plugged into the computer which are all shown in the bios. But if I boot from USB I can't select (find) any HDD.

Thanks

There is no IDE device connected.

All HDDs are Sata

I am very sorry to bothered you but somehow magically after about the 30th restart it just started and showed some windows error which I was able to repair. Still not sure where this malfunction came from (since the corrupted hdd was not the active hdd)

***Update***: No it shows the error again

reseting bios made me able to acess the HDDs via Windows Installer. My previous windows installation was not detected. After formating C:\ and reinstalling now it seems to work.

Comment: Is there a floppy disk in the 3&frac12; inch drive? (Or a unbootable pendrive/SD/whatever modern version of a floppy is on your PC).

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?